# PDPage.getStream function does not exist

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox for reading pdf documents.
But i can not use the function getStream for PDPage. Regarding the documentation this functions should exists:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/

I am using the 2.0.0 Snapshot version of PdfBox with Maven.
I already tried to download the .jar files from the website and use them instead of the ones from the maven repo, but this did not work either.

The exact error from eclipse is: *The method getStream() is undefined for the type PDPage.*

Here is the pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.rwth-aachen.prime</groupId>
<artifactId>prime</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Prime Project</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<repositories>
    <!-- <repository> <id>libs</id> ${project.basedir} <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url> 
        </repository> -->
    <!-- <repository> <id>pdfbox</id> <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url> 
        </repository> -->
    <!-- <repository>
        <id>pdfbox</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url>
    </repository>-->
    <repository>
      <id>ApacheSnapshot</id>
      <name>Apache Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <!-- For mime type extraction -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.3</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- needed for setting lazy loaded elements = null -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging -->
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> 
        <version>1.7.5</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.2</version> </dependency> -->
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.2</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
                </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>1.44</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>prime</finalName>
</build>

  <properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <start-class>spring.Application</start-class>
  </properties>
</project>
```

This is the result of mvn dependencie:tree

```
[INFO] de.rwth-aachen.prime:prime:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.57:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.57:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.57:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.57:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog:jackson-jsog:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.32:compile
[INFO] +- org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-svg11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xslfo:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xmldsig-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.engio:mbassador:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.arnx:wmf2svg:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.44:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:1.44:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] \- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Can you post the full pom and the result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: You're using TIKA 1.8 and PDFBox 2.0 at the same time. But TIKA is a release version and PDFBox 2.0 is an experimental snapshot. The 2.0 version has a different API than the 1.8 version, which TIKA 1.8 uses.

Comment: Thanks for this information, but i dont get the problem. Does this mean that also a PDFBox 1.8 is available in the system and so this one is used instead of the 2.0 version and so i can not access the function? With TIKA itself i do not have any trouble and the jar file of PDFBox2.0 is available in the project but not the jar file of PDFBox 1.8. Do you have any solution to use both Tika and PDFBox2.0? By the way, i tried the newest TIKA version, but this does not make any difference.

Comment: I looked into the maven-repository and the tika-core does not use pdfbox, only the tika-parsers use pdfbox, so in my opinion that can not be the problem. Does anybody have another idea what can be the problem?

Comment: I also tried to create a new clean project and only use the PDFBox dependencie to avoid problems with other dependencies. But the error still exists in the clean project, so in my opinion there is a problem with the PDFBox 2.0 Snapshot jar file. In the source.jar of the newest snapshot, the function getStream() does not exist in the PDPage.class. I tried to find the source code of the version 2.0, but i could not find it online. Does anybody know how to access the sourcecode of PDFBox 2.0?